# jquery click function in not fire

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <script src="jq/jquery-1.10.2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {

            $("table tr td").click(function () {

                var div_top = $(this).position().top;
                var div_left = $(this).position().left;

                var new_div = "<div style='position:absolute;z-index:2;top:" + div_top + "px;left:" + div_left + "px;width:30px;height:23px;background:red;margin:0px auto;'></div>";
                $(".main").html(new_div + $(".main").html());
            });
        });
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div class="main">
        <table class="tbl-bottom">
            <tr><td>temp</td><td></td><td></td></tr>
            <tr><td></td><td>temp</td><td></td></tr>
        </table>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

When first time click in "td" of table then show div in that "td" but after click in another "td" click function in not fire.

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Answer (score 2):

You are completely rewriting the table on click :

```
 $(".main").html(new_div + $(".main").html()); //.html() rewrite table
```

So your table containing the click events no longer exist.

Try using `.prepend` instead :

```
 $(".main").prepend(new_div);
```

Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/ezyLV/2/

---

## That was an edit that might not be needed after rereading the current code

### Still keeping it in case, might be usefull.

Now, that the table is not rewrited every click, you'll need to prevent the div to be prepended every click.

To do that, simply convert your `div` into a jQuery object and move it outside the click event :

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var new_div = $("<div style='position:absolute;z-index:2;width:30px;height:23px;background:red;margin:0px auto;'></div>");
    $("table tr td").click(function () {
         var div_top = $(this).position().top;
         var div_left = $(this).position().left;

         new_div.css({top : div_top, left : div_left});

         $(".main").prepend(new_div);
     });
});
```

That way, you are not prepending a new div every click, but only moving it and changing its CSS.

Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/ezyLV/1/

Answer (score 1):

You need to use event delegation since you're adding the table back repeatedly.

Change:

```
$("table tr td").click(function () {
```

to:

```
$('div.main').on('click', "table tr td", function () {
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/ezyLV/)**

Answer (score 1):

You're replacing all your html with this line...

```
$(".main").html(new_div + $(".main").html());
```

That causes you to lose your click handler.

You should append your new div without replacing all your html.  Something like...

```
$('.main').append(new_div);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this will work:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

            $("table tr td").click(function () {

                var div_top = $(this).position().top;
                var div_left = $(this).position().left;

                var new_div = "<div style='position:absolute;top:" + div_top + "px;left:" + div_left + "px;width:30px;height:23px;background:red;margin:0px auto;'></div>";
                $(this).html(new_div);
            });
        });
```

I think you want to add `new_div` in your `<td>`. That's why you used .html(). In other case you want to use [append](http://api.jquery.com/append/)

[OP with html()](http://jsfiddle.net/ACjaJ/6/)

[example with append](http://jsfiddle.net/ACjaJ/7/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('td').each(function(){
     $(this).click(function(){
        ......
     });
});
```

Your code goes within the each function.

This should iterate through all the cells on the page.

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace...
$(".main").html .... Etc...
With
    $(this).html(new_div);